# implementation of HeapBasedPriorityQueue

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator, priority-queue

The following methods don't work correctly:

```
 public Iterator<E> elements() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private int currentIndex = 0;
            private int expectedModificationCount = modificationCount;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            return currentIndex < size;
        }

        @Override
        public K next() {
            // checkModificationCount();
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return heap[currentIndex++].getKey();
        }

        private void checkModificationCount() {
            if (expectedModificationCount != modificationCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException("Priority queue modified during     iteration");
            }
        }
    };
}


public Iterator<E> elements() {
    return new Iterator<E>() {
        private int currentIndex = 0;
        private int expectedModificationCount = modificationCount;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            //checkModificationCount();
            return currentIndex < size;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            checkModificationCount();
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            E element = heap[currentIndex].getElement();
            currentIndex++;
            return element;
        }

        private void checkModificationCount() {
            if (expectedModificationCount != modificationCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException("Priority queue modified during iteration");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Iterator should be ended after modification of the priority queue, if I run for example the following test method:

```
@Test
void testContinuingElements() {
    PriorityQueue<String, Integer> pq = new HeapBasedPriorityQueue<>(STRING_COMPARATOR);
    pq.insert("test1", 1);
    Iterator<Integer> elements1 = pq.elements();
    pq.insert("test2", 2);
    Iterator<Integer> elements2 = pq.elements();
    assertFalse(elements1.hasNext(), "Iterator should be ended after modification of the priority queue");
    assertThrows(ConcurrentModificationException.class, elements1::next, "Iterator should throw ConcurrentModificationException after modification of the priority queue");
    assertTrue(elements2.hasNext(), "Iterator generated after last change can continue");
    assertEquals(1, elements2.next(), "Iterator generated after last change can continue");
}
```

the `hasNext()` should return false, to pass the following line of the test method but it doesn't.

`assertFalse(elements1.hasNext(), "Iterator should be ended after modification of the priority queue")`

Comment: Nothing in your iterator's `hasNext()` implementation is affected by subsequent modifications.  It reports only on whether the iterator's `currentIndex` is less than the heap's `size`.  If you want also to take the `expectedModificationCount` into account then do.  What prevents you?

Comment: What is the difference between both `Iterator<E> elements()`? Why should `elements1` be ended after an insert following its instantiation? I concede the API documentation is overly thin in specifying behaviour with concurrent modifications, e.g. *should modifications between instantiation and first use be forbidden or allowed?*